# Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Tags: python, pip

Recently i was trying to install speechrecognition in python on vs code but it shows an error i have tried using command prompt but it doesnt work.
here are the codes

```
'PS C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\python> pip install speechRecognition      
 Collecting speechRecognition
 Using cached SpeechRecognition-3.8.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (32.8 MB)
 ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [WinError 32] The process cannot 
 access the file because it is being used by another process: 
 'C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-tracker- 
 e9sg4n2d\\7fd58c0c5ee7cc27d392ed0613487ea8ab5f15fb7f011361ee8a8fae'
 Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
python -m pip install speechRecognition
```